# HTTPS between two devices

Tags: ssl, https, embedded, tls1.2

I am attempting to securely communicate between two embedded devices.

One (referred to as the server) is acting as a WiFi access point, similar to a router. It runs a HTTP server at a constant IP address. My goal is to enable SSL on this server.

The other (referred to as the client) connects to the server's WiFi access point and makes request to the HTTP server in order to provide the server with information it needs to operate.

Every example I can find that attempt this uses self-signed certificates. From my (limited) understanding of TLS, these are not secure and should only be used for development.

I believe what I want is a trusted certificate. However, every example I can find generates these certificates for websites. I am struggling to understand:

1. If it is possible to generate trusted certificates for this application, and
2. How to do so.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: *"From my (limited) understanding of TLS, these are not secure and should only be used for development."* - this understanding is wrong. Self-signed certificates are secure as long as they are properly validated, i.e. not simply blindly trusted. The main point of certificates issued by a public CA is that it scales much better to build a trust relationship when lots of clients and lots of certificates are involved (i.e. usual web traffic). But for small setups like in your case self-signed certificates work fine by letting the few clients know beforehand which certificate to expect.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and apologies for the delay. Can you clarify what you mean when you say "letting the few clients know beforehand which certificates to expect"? Does this just mean that the server sends it's certificate to the client and the client compares it to the one it has?

Comment: There need to be some way to __securely__ transmit the information about the expected certificate to the client. How this is done depends on the exact use case: for example the certificate can be shipped together within the application when, it can be delivered by an otherwise trusted HTTPS connection (where a certificate issued by a trusted CA is used), the client can get some paper with the expected certificate fingerprint for comparison ...